# I can not install php with freetype support [Ubuntu]

Tags: php, ubuntu, freetype

I am trying to install php from source again and I have done it several times by now. I really need freetype support, and when I try to compile php everything is alright except for the freetype.

PHP VERSION: 8.0.1

> Error: configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-freetype-dir

terminal command:

```
sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php --with-mysqli=mysqlnd  --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-jpeg --with-zlib --with-kerberos --enable-gd   --with-freetype-dir=/usr/local/freetype2/ --with-freetype
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php)

> To enable support for FreeType 2 add --with-freetype-dir=DIR. **As of
> PHP 7.4.0 use --with-freetype instead, which relies on pkg-config**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I should have read the manual more carefully.  Sorry for taking you time.